# Why should composition follow the open-closed-principle?

Tags: java

Why should composition follow the "open to extension, close to modification" principle?

I understand: If you want to add functionality in the class, you just write new code and use composition to get to that code.
But do you just modify the code in which you have a composition? Because you add composition to that code so you modify that code.

Example:

Before, it is this:

```
public class Example{
public void Walk(){
    //walking
}
}
```

And after:

```
public class Example{

    RunClass r = new RunClass(); // I add this

public void Walk(){
    //walking
}

public void Run(){ // I also add this
    r.run();        
}
}
```

So this means I modified this class.

Answer (score 5):

> You need to take a look a the definitions first.
>   Composition is just a "has a" relationship, while inheritance Is a "is a" relationship.
>   The open closed principle is about changing the behavior without altering the source code of a class. By themselves they don't ensure the OCP.
>   Design patterns follow the principle through composition or/and inheritance.  E.g. The strategy design pattern uses composition to change bahavior at runtime, while the template method pattern uses inheritance to change behavior at compile time. So composition allows extension at runtime so while inheritance allows it at compile time. If you want your class to be sealed (can't be subclassed) the only available option is composition.
>   OCP is not ensured by composition, unless your design is loosely coupled. Remember that composition is just a "has a" relationship, which just says that your class has an instance of an object, but if you have to modify your code to change that instance, that doesn't follow the OCP. However if you use inversion of control (IoC), that composition becomes loosely coupled, therefore you don't have to change the code in your class. Here is an example:

Composition that doesn't follow the OCP

```
  public class Bike {
    Wheel wheel = new LargeWheel();

    public void go(){
      wheel.go();
  }
```

Composition that follows the OCP (through IoC)

```
  public class Bike {
    Wheel wheel;

    public setWheel(Wheel wheel){
      this.wheel = wheel;
    }

    public void go(){
      wheel.go();
  }
```

In the first case you need to modify the code if you want a different type of wheel, but in the second one you "inject" the wheel instance you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using composition in an OCP way.

This would be something that follows OCP:

```
public class Example2{

    Example e = new Example(); 
    RunClass r = new RunClass();

    public void Walk(){
        e.Walk()
    }

    public void Run(){ 
        r.run();        
    }
}
```

An alternative is that `Example2` inherits `Example`:

```
public class Example2 extends Example{

    RunClass r = new RunClass();

    public void Run(){ 
        r.run();        
    }
}
```

`Example` doesn't change but is composed into `Example2`.

Comment: I don't think the first example follows the OCP, bc if you need to change "e" or "r" to a different instance you have to change the code. In the case you can use the strategy pattern which uses IoC to pass an instance instead of creating it inside the class

Answer (score 2):

The main point of open-closed is clear when you apply it to a class you don't have source code for, it just comes in a JAR as a dependency. That class is positively **closed** for modification -- you can only use it as-is. The *open* part means that the class should be designed in such a way that you as its consumer are able to extend its behavior to meet your needs. Composition is one way to use that class and add behavior of your own.